# Show merge parents in git log when using pretty format string

Tags: git, git-log

Git log [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) says:

> If the commit is a merge, and if the pretty-format is not oneline, email or raw, an additional line is inserted before the Author: line. This line begins with "Merge: " and the sha1s of ancestral commits are printed, separated by spaces.

Buy I'm using format.pretty in my git global config, and I don't see the "Merge line".

I could emulate it with the %p (or %P) parameters shown in the [git-log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> %P: parent hashes
>
> %p: abbreviated parent hashes

But that shows an empty "Merge:" line if the commit is not a merge commit.

Is there a way to emulate the standard log behavior about merge commits parents while using a pretty format string?

Comment: use this alias: git log --oneline --decorate --oneline --graph

Comment: @CodeWizard I have that aliased but I'm trying to config the default log to show some extra info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to do this at the moment.  The problem is that you must include `%p` or `%P` if and only if this is a merge commit, but there is no "test some condition, execute format directives based on result" format directive.  (The closest we get are the `%<`, `%>`, etc directives.)

There is one way to work around this but it is slow: use `git rev-list` to get the commit IDs you want, then log them one at a time with `git log -1` or `git log --no-walk`.  This way you can run whatever code you like before invoking `git log`, such as testing "is this a merge commit".  If it is a merge commit, add the desired directives to the format, and if not, leave them out.  For instance:

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read hash; do
    if is-merge $hash; then fmt="... %p ..."; else fmt="... ..."; fi
    git log --no-walk --format="$fmt" $hash
done
```

where `is-merge` checks the parent count.  (To do that more efficiently, use `git rev-list --parents` and alter the `read` command to `read hash parents` or `read hash parent1 rest`, after which you can test `$parents` or `$rest`.  If you're writing in bash you can use arrays.)